# What is the best way to let users upload pictures to my WPF application

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF intranet app running in Trusted mode (local only).
I would like the users to be able to upload an image and attach it to an article on my newsletters section. I am having trouble deciding where these images will be stored.
Please provide me with your opinions.
At present I have a few ideas myself;
I could have an aspx page that runs parallel to this app, and run this inside a browser(I-frame). This page could then handle the upload and display of the image.
I could also, have the users copy directly to a network share.
It seems that there should be a more elegant sollution that I am not aware of.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't force the solution towards ASPX just because you know how to do it there. It's unnatural to build a page, host browser to show that page etc, just so you could upload an image.

It's actually quite simpler to do it in a desktop client than on web page. You have a "Load File Dialog" - use that to get to the filepath the user wants to upload, and when you have that you can either:

- copy it (inside your application) to your share,
- or if you have a service - send it through some method call,
- or you can even store it inside a database (recommended if the files are small)

There's really lots of options here... it depends if your client has connection to db, do you have service in between, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of saving it directly to the DB. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Saving the image to the database proved to be the perfect solution. Thank you.